# How to apply class only for IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have this class in CSS and i need to change it when its IE. I want to remove `padding-bottom`. How can I do that?

I don't want to add another CSS file, I want to change only one property in one class.

```
.container-wrapp{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried this but without success:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.container-wrapp{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? IE 10 and up **do not** support conditional comments at all.

Comment: how can i fix this for 10 and up ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For IE10+ you can do the following:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   .container-wrapp{padding-bottom:0;}
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/cgyg5oa5/1/) (Note that the text is red only in IE 10+)

```css
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none),
(-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .red {
    color: red
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red">text</div>
```

NB: Using hacks like these are generally frowned upon. Use with caution.

Comment: @None - Take a look at the demo fiddle. I tested it in IE using the emulator and the text appeared red only in versions IE 10+

Comment: Which version of IE do you have?

Comment: IE11 i think so because i have windows 10 installed so i cant find which verison im using

Comment: In the IE Menu bar click Help->About Internet explorer - That will show you the version

Comment: my bad...because windows 10 have somehow two ie browsers so its working for ie 11 and 10

Comment: for IE Edge, use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528940/how-to-detect-ie-and-edge-browsers-in-css#answer-43529012

Answer (score 1):

Create a stylesheet file `ie.css` and use `if` AFTER the global style definition this way:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='ie.css'/>
<![endif]-->
```

This should work.

Comment: It is deprecated and removed since IE 10: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link [How to create an ie only stylesheet](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) , You need to create a separate style sheet for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think for best practice you should write IE conditional statement inside the  tag that inside has a link to your special ie specific style sheet. This **HAS TO BE** after your custom css link so it overrides the css property. Here is an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Hope this will helps you!

IE 10 and onward no longer support conditional comments. From the MS official website:

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5.

Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

If you desperately need to target ie, you can use this jQuery code to add a ie class to and then use .ie class in your css to target ie browsers.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
 $("html").addClass("ie");
}
```

Comment: Can you please verify if it's loading the css `all-ie-only.css` by checking page source?

Comment: Updated my answer please check.