# Media queries not working in specific IE query

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I am trying to use media queries in only one browser (IE) but nothing I have tried is working.

For example:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    /* Styles go here for IE */
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .article {
            width: 100%!important;
        }
    }
 }
```

I am trying to have a media query that only works for IE and nothing else, but this isn't having any affect. I have also tried:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none), (max-width: 1320px) {
    div#desktop-nav {
        padding-left: 0px!important;
        padding-right: 0px!important;
    }
}
```

I added the max-width to the end of the media query.

If anyone has any clue how to do media queries for one specific browser please let me know

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], so we can see what it is that actually doesn't work.

Comment: Also, which IE versions do you want to target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to target IE 10+, so try using the `all` selector instead of the `screen` selector.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   /* IE10+ CSS */
}
```

If you're trying to target IE 9 or below, you'll have to load a conditional stylesheet, like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can find more detail about this and other Microsoft browsers here:

[how to detect IE and Edge browsers in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528940/how-to-detect-ie-and-edge-browsers-in-css/43529012#43529012)

Answer (score 0):

You have separated the conditions with commas and not the `and` keyword

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) and (max-width: 1320px) {
    div#desktop-nav {
        padding-left: 0px!important;
        padding-right: 0px!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just gave this a shot, and it doesn't seem to change the outcome.

Comment: Yes, it is making changes only in IE, but just the media query isn't working.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on mac to test this out on actual IE, sorry